# How to know if the form is really serialized?

Tags: jquery, serialization

i have this form to serialize once i click the submit button,

```
   <form class="cashier_forms" action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/'.$this->uri->segment(1).'/'.$this->uri->segment(2)?>/addCashierCount" id="form_cashier_count" rel="ajax_message">
       <p id="cashier_count_p" class="hidden">
          <label for="recipe_id">Count</label>
          <input placeholder="Cashier count for this Recipe" class="all_curve_small cashier_inputs" name="cashier_count" id="cashier_id" />
          <input id="yield_recipe_id" type="text" name="yield_id_input" value="<?php echo $ayr_recipe->yieldID?>" />
          <input type="text" name="count_date" value="<?php echo $date_now?>" />
          <input type="submit" class="buttons count_submit" rel="form_<?php echo $this->tbl_count_name ?>" value="Add Count" />
       </p>
    </form>
```

and this is my jquery which supposedly serializes my form..

```
   $('.count_submit').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var form    = '#'+ $(this).attr('rel');
      var url  = $(form).attr('action');
      var target  = '#'+ $(form).attr('rel');
      $(target).slideUp();
      $.post(url, $(form).serialize(),function(data) {
         $(target).html(data).slideDown(function(){
            if(data == '<div class="ok">Added</div>'){
            setTimeout(refresh,3000)
            window.location = '<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/cashier/cashier_lo';
            }
         });
      });
    });
```

but when the action is being processed, it stores no data, i think the form is not being serialized..can someone please check if i miss sumthing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't give you the form:

```
var form = '#'+ $(this).attr('rel');
```

This gives you the `rel` attribute of the submit button (which by the way doesn't even have such attribute). And then it is meaningless to call the `.serialize()` method on it. To access the form. Remember that inside your click handler this points to the element that was clicked (a.k.a the button, not the form). So:

```
var form = $(this).closest('form');
```

This being said a much better thing is to subscribe to the submit event of the form, not the click event of the button. What if the user presses Enter while inside the input field? The form will be submitted and your click handler will never run.

So let's clean things up:

```
$('#form_cashier_count').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var target = form.attr('rel');
    $(target).slideUp();
    $.post(this.action, form.serialize(), function(data) {
        $(target).html(data).slideDown(function() {
            if (data == '<div class="ok">Added</div>') {
                setTimeout(refresh, 3000);
                window.location = '<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/cashier/cashier_lo';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So what you are looking for? What issues are you encountering with this code? I explained why the `$(form).serialize()` doesn't do anything in your code.

Comment: i don't know, but i implemented what you just told me to, but still it won't work.my button now becomes unclickable..

Comment: Maybe that's because of the sliding up? Is the AJAX request being sent to your server? Use a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug to inspect the request.

Comment: no, not at all..previously, without using your the edited code you gave, the request is being sent to the server, but when i used your code the button now becomes unclickable.

Comment: Maybe you have some other script that disables it?

Comment: I reused my old code and the action of the form was successfully processed, however it stores no data.when i checked the post data using firebug, the post is empty..

Comment: I already explained you why it is empty. Didn't you read my answer? When you subscribe to the click event of the submit button `$(this)` gives you the button that was clicked, **not the form**. If you want to retrieve the form you have to use `var form = $(this).closest('form');` in this case. Now `form.serialize()` will contain the form data. Please read my answer once again carefully this time.

Comment: Hi @Darin Dimitrov, I reviewed my code and found the problem. I'm glad your solution worked. Thanks